# SQL Query returning name

Tags: sql

I have the following query that returns fine but instead of showing the `id` is there away that I can get it to show `default_ps_products_manufacturers.name`

```
SELECT  `manufacturer_id` 
FROM  `default_ps_products` 
INNER JOIN  `default_ps_products_manufacturers` ON default_ps_products.manufacturer_id = default_ps_products_manufacturers.id
```

Comment: Yes: just add the desired column to the SELECT list in place of `manufacturer_id`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try including that column in the `SELECT`?:

```
SELECT m.name
FROM  `default_ps_products` p
INNER JOIN  `default_ps_products_manufacturers` m
    ON p.manufacturer_id = m.id
```

Answer (score 2):

So Just add the column which you want to select like this

```
SELECT  default_ps_products_manufacturers.name  
FROM  default_ps_products 
INNER JOIN  default_ps_products_manufacturers 
ON default_ps_products.manufacturer_id = default_ps_products_manufacturers.id
```